# Node.js express website accessible online

Tags: javascript, node.js, iis, express

I have a website built using node.js and express in my iis webserver.

I can access the site by http://localhost:3000 and so can everyone else who are in the same domain when I put my files in /inetpub/wwwroot/ folder.

My question is, how do I make that website accessible from the internet/different domains?

My config.js file which is called from when I run app.js :

```
var config = {
local: {
    mode: 'local',
    port: 3000,
    mongo: {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 27017
    }
}
```

How would I modify my config file to reflect the changes I want? Thanks.

Comment: If you are using IIS why don't you configure IIS to route to port 3000 on the machine running th enode instance.

Comment: You mean do a URL rewrite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really done at the router level.  You'll need a public IP that routes traffic to your local machine.  Then you set up DNS for the IP (through a domain registrar). Though, typically, serving a site is a big security risk.  You'll want to have a dedicated server set up, away from your local development machine... and keep it patched.

Comment: I already have the designated webserver, can't I just route the traffic so that when anyone(internet) goes to http://mysite:3000 it will point to my localhost:3000? Or is that not possible?

Comment: Yes, but typically it's not done on port 3000.  Usually it's 80 for http and 443 for https.  You'll likely want to forward port 80 to your localhost port 3000 (in the router), or you'll likely need to have the router updated to also forward port 3000 traffic.   It's likely blocked by default by the router, network and/or firewalls.

Comment: So I would use something like ARR (Application request routing)  to forward port 80 to 3000? Sorry, I am still not getting the full picture.

Comment: Well, on a linux server I use iptables to do the routing.  It really depends on how your network is set up though.  Is this a network you set up?   Or is there another group of people that manage it?  If it's something like a simple home network, it would all be configured in the router and possibly at the machine's firewall (if there is one).

Comment: I only get a small part of the network designated for my site. So someone else is managing it. I was thinking, is it possible to have the request from the internet go and the webserver proxy to port 3000? Or have port 3000 open to the web?

Comment: Yes, you can set up a proxy, though it can be a little tricky and depends on what software is being used.  The simplest would be to have port 3000 open to the web, and serve the site on port 3000 (you'll likely need to send a request for this).  The next simplest is to proxy requests on port 80 to the website (there are a lot of ways to do this, I use iptables)

Comment: I agree, well looks like I got plans on how to get this working, thanks a bunch!